# Why MapFragment is not recognized by visual studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, scrollview, mapfragment

I have a map inside a scrollview and when we try to scroll around the map, scroll view comes up and scrolls itself but not the map. I'm trying to fix this issue with a code that I found on google but visual studio is showing some errors:

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MapFragment' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (MasterDetailPageNavigation)
```

and

```
Error CS0115: 'TouchableMapFragment.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (MasterDetailPageNavigation)
```

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
//using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace MasterDetailPageNavigation
{
    public class TouchableMapFragment : MapFragment
    {
        public event EventHandler TouchDown;
        public event EventHandler TouchUp;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var root = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var wrapper = new TouchableWrapper(Activity);
            wrapper.SetBackgroundColor(Resources.GetColor(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
            ((ViewGroup)root).AddView(wrapper,
              new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));

            wrapper.TouchUp = () =>
            {
                if (TouchUp != null)
                    TouchUp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            };
            wrapper.TouchDown = () =>
            {
                if (TouchDown != null)
                    TouchDown(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            };

            return root;
        }

        class TouchableWrapper : FrameLayout
        {
            public Action TouchDown;
            public Action TouchUp;

            #region ctors
            protected TouchableWrapper(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
              : base(javaReference, transfer) { }
            public TouchableWrapper(Context context)
              : this(context, null) { }
            public TouchableWrapper(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
              : this(context, attrs, 0) { }
            public TouchableWrapper(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
              : base(context, attrs, defStyle) { }
            #endregion

            public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
            {
                switch (e.Action)
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                        if (TouchDown != null)
                            TouchDown();
                        break;
                    case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    case MotionEventActions.Up:
                        if (TouchUp != null)
                            TouchUp();
                        break;
                }

                return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also this code has a .AXML file that I will include below but I never had used something like this before, I'm working with XAML from Xamarin, where I have to put this axml?

the xaml I talked about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="my.awesome.namespace.TouchableMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Sorry if this is a dummy question but I'm studding alone and it's being a little bit hard.

Comment: Where did you find that code snippet? is this the link? https://gist.github.com/Cheesebaron/db2b721c37f4066da25c#file-view-axml

Comment: @Train yes. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You should install the [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps) package from NuGet.

> The Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package contains the
>   Xamarin.Android bindings for the Google Play Services Maps API. To add
>   the Google Play Services Map package, right-click the References
>   folder of your project in the Solution Explorer and click Manage NuGet
>   Packages...:

You can get the detailed steps about how to install this package from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api#-install-the-xamaringoogleplayservicesmaps-package-from-nuget).

After installed the package, use the namespace `Android.Gms.Maps`, the [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) is a class in the namespace `Android.Gms.Maps`:

```
using Android.Gms.Maps;
```

Comment: And how about the axml? At first look I thought ot was a mistake by author of this code, then I saw the structure difference and realized that its something new for me. Do I need to add this axml to my project? Where do I have to save it? In which folder?

Comment: @SandroBenevides Yes, I think you need to add this axml to your project. It's a Android layout file and it created TouchableMapFragment. And I also think you can try to put it under Resource --> Layout folder

Comment: I have installed the nuget package, added the namespace as you said, have cleaned and updated solution but still getting "The type or namespace name 'MapFragment' could not be found "

Comment: @SandroBenevides It should work. Can you try write directly `public class TouchableMapFragment : Android.Gms.Maps.MapFragment`? Delete the obj and bin folder, clean and rebuild, restart the VS.

Comment: Doing that makes visual studio paint "Android.Gms.Maps" in gray and the part ".MapFragment" stays underlined in red, and it shows the message: "type name or namespace MapFragment can not be found.

Comment: @SandroBenevides Can you please provide me a sample project so that I can check it for you? It works on my side. BTW, which verison of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps are you installing? You can try uninstall and install the latest version again.